# Memory issue with threads (tinythread, C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory

I debug a strange memory issue: When a multithreaded algorithm runs in a loop its memory consumption increases with every iteration although the heap checker of of GooglePerformanceTools says there is no leak. Finally I have made a separate minimal program that reproduces the bug. It seems that the threads are the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "tinythread.h"
using namespace std;


int a(0);
void doNothingAtAll(void*)
{
    ++a;
}

void startAndJoin100()
{   
    vector<tthread::thread*> vThreads;
    for(int i=0;i<100;++i)
    {   
        vThreads.push_back(new tthread::thread(doNothingAtAll,NULL));
    }
    while(!vThreads.empty())
    {
            tthread::thread* pThread(vThreads.back());
            pThread->join();
            delete pThread;
            vThreads.pop_back();
    }
}

int main()
{       
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
        cout<<"calling startAndJoin100()"<<endl;
        startAndJoin100();
        cout<<"all threads joined"<<endl;
        cin.get();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

main() calls 10 times startAndJoin100(). It waits for a key stroke after each iteration so that one can take the memory consumption which is (under Ubuntu 17.10, 64-bit):

```
VIRT
2.1 GB
4 GB
5.9 GB
7.8 GB
9.6 GB
11.5 GB
13.4 GB
15.3 GB
17.2 GB
19.0 GB
```

Note: C++11 can't be used and the program must compile on Linux and Windows, thus tinythread is used. Minimal test code with Makefile:
[geom.at/_downloads/testTinyThread.zip](http://geom.at/_downloads/testTinyThread.zip)

Comment: You could (on Ubuntu) use [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html). You should read a [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). Use also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: I think it's the usual problem of the Linux kernel not unmapping pages as you free memory. That will make it *seem* like you have a leak, but it's a false positive.

Comment: On another note, you have a data-race as multiple threads try to read and write to `a` simultaneously. That leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ++a just keeps the compiler from optimizing away an empty function. I have replaced the outer for(i=0;i<10;++i) loop by while(true) now: The virtual memory consumption increases step by step to 624 GB and stays stable then. I know that the kernel does not (or not immediately) unmap pages when memory is freed. But shouldn't the assigned memory pages be re-used?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The software must be portable, so pthreads is not an option. I have also used Valgrind. No leak found.

Comment: TinyThreads is less common and less portable than Pthreads (and internally using Pthreads on Linux). Every Linux system has Pthreads. So your "portability" is an illusion.

Comment: If portability is a concern, use [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) and its [`<thread>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) standard library. So just demand that your users have a C++11 implementation; or stick to Pthread which is available on many systems.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch TinyThread compiles under Windows, Linux, Mac, FreeBSD and consists of just one .h and .cpp file. No extra library to be linked. I think pthreads require an additional library under Windows.

Comment: So what? As I said, you should require a standard C++11 implementation; what that implementation requires is the concern of your users.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch C++11 is not available, I create libraries that must also run on old systems. RedHat6, CentOS6.4, VS2008, ...

Comment: On old RedHat or CentOS systems, you can compile a *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (e.g. GCC 7 providing C++11) from its source code; and pthreads exist on them. Notice that Pthread is a POSIX standard, and C++11 an ISO one. Better base your work on standard tools. TinyThread is an extra library that your code depends on (and that most systems don't have). I never heard of it before your question, so it is not even a popular library. You could use popular frameworks like [Qt](http://qt.io) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Software compiled with a recent GCC won't run on CentOS6.4.

Comment: As I said, you need to compile the recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler from its source code (e.g. [gcc-7.2.0.tar.xz](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-7.2.0/gcc-7.2.0.tar.xz)...) on the old Linux system. I did that in the past, it works well (even if compiling GCC takes a lot of time). Of course a binary compiled on a recent Debian/Sid won't run on an old RedHat from the previous century.

Comment: Ah, okay, that's an option. But does not solve the problem for VS2008

Comment: I don't know tinythread - but it's entirely possible that somewhere in the background there it's keeping a whole load of data; and while never a detectable leak, it is data that is never released.  Even with what @Someprogrammerdude said, the pages should be at least reused.  Once you've tried doing this with std::thread or pthread, you'll have taken the non-standard wrapping library out the equation and be in a better position.  (and remove the undefined behavior - it is after all, UB!)

Comment: After a short reading of the code of timythread, it looks like it uses PThreads on Linux, so if you write the same test code with pthread and it still gives the same result bug report ubuntu, if it now doesn't behave that way bug report tinythread.

Comment: @Surt You are right. I have just rewritten the minimal example: No problem when pthread is used. But it is nevertheless strange: With tinythread htop reports 624 GB virtual memory usage while the system has only 64 GB RAM and 11 GB swap space. So it CAN'T be a real memory leak.

Comment: By the way, why has the question been downvoted? I think it shows effort and is not off-topic

Answer (score 2):

I answer my own question, this may be useful for somebody later:

Conclusion:

1) I'd really like to keep TinyThread because C++11 is unavailable (VS2008 and old Linux Systems must be supported) and no additional library shall be linked (TinyThread consists only of an *.h and *.cpp file while Boost and other solutions I know require linking a DLL).

2) Valgrind and the heap checker of the GooglePerformanceTools do not report memory leaks and I have looked into the code - it seems to be correct although the virtual memory consumption increases drastically in the minimal example posted above. It seems that the system does not re-use the previously assigned memory pages and I have not found an explanation for this behavior. Thus I do not blame TinyThread++ but it works when pthreads are used directly instead.

3) The workaround: There is a C alternative called TinyCThread: https://tinycthread.github.io/ that works also for C++ and it does not cause the problems observed with TinyThread++.